# Firebase Phone Authentication Stoped working in My Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Phone Authentication in an app I've created but suddenly its stopped working from today and I'm using App Check as well, any one know the solution ?

**Console Log :**

> W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 6077): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: -9: Integrity API error (-9): Binding to the service in the Play Store has failed. This can be due to having an old Play Store version installed on the device.
> D/FirebaseAuth( 6077): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +97471******, error - This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.

I have tried multiple solutions

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/error-codes#iErr_9

Comment: we have tested on latest mobile with latest google playstore version but its still having same issue [same logs].

Comment: Well, unsure how you are expecting any help without providing any details - [ask]. Why don't you open a ticket with the play store's support? "*or check the logcat for more details*" - Did you check these logs? Furthermore you've stated you've tried multiple solutions, yet not a single one is listed/highlighted in your question.

Comment: What version of Firebase Authentication and App Check are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @pcba-dev i am using firebase_auth: 4.16.0 and firebase_app_check: 0.2.1+8 versions